# Have trouble in ‘ndt matching’ with my custom pcd file

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run ‘ndt matching’ using my custom pcd file, which was made using ‘ndt mapping’.  I made a launch file refer to ‘moriyama quick start’ demo. I uploaded my launch file :

```
<launch>  
  <arg name="period_in_ms" default="10"/>   
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="world_to_map" args="788935 -2362 -82 0 0 0 /world /map $(arg period_in_ms)"/>  
  <!-- map_to_mobility_tf -->  
  <node pkg="tf"  type="static_transform_publisher" name="map_to_mobility" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /map /mobility 10" />  
  <!-- pointcloud -->  
  <node pkg="map_file" type="points_map_loader" name="points_map_loader" args="noupdate $(env HOME)/Desktop/KimTaekyung/mapping2matching/190614_DATA_FIRST_NDTwIMU.pcd"/>  
  <!-- VLP-16 -->  
  <arg name="velodyne_calib" default="$(find velodyne_pointcloud)/params/VLP16db.yaml"/>  
  <include file="$(find velodyne_pointcloud)/launch/velodyne_vlp16.launch">  
    <arg name="calibration" value="$(arg velodyne_calib)"/>  
  </include>  
  <!-- setting path parameter -->  
  <arg name="get_height" value="true" />  
  <!-- Setup -->  
  <include file="$(find runtime_manager)/scripts/setup_tf.launch">  
    <arg name="x" value="1.2" />  
    <arg name="y" value="0.0" />  
    <arg name="z" value="2.0" />   
    <arg name="yaw" value="0.0" />  
    <arg name="pitch" value="0.0" />  
    <arg name="roll" value="0.0" />  
    <arg name="frame_id" value="/base_link" />  
    <arg name="child_frame_id" value="/velodyne" />  
    <arg name="period_in_ms" value="10"/>  
  </include>  
  <include file="$(find model_publisher)/launch/vehicle_model.launch" />  
  <!-- voxel_grid_filter -->  
  <arg name="sync" default="false" />  
  <arg name="node_name" default="voxel_grid_filter" />  
  <arg name="points_topic" default="velodyne_points" />  
  <arg name="output_log" default="false" />  
  <node pkg="points_downsampler" name="$(arg node_name)" type="$(arg node_name)">  
    <param name="points_topic" value="$(arg points_topic)" />  
    <remap from="/points_raw" to="/sync_drivers/points_raw" if="$(arg sync)" />  
    <param name="output_log" value="$(arg output_log)" />  
  </node>  
  <!-- nmea2tfpose -->  
  <include file="$(find gnss_localizer)/launch/nmea2tfpose.launch"/>  
</launch>
```

‘ 788935 -2362 -82’ is the first GPS coordinate in my rosbag file when I ran ‘ndt mapping’. I think I had followed all I need to do, but ‘ndt matching’ is not working. The ‘base_link’ is just following the ‘gps’ frame, and ‘gps’ frame is very far from pointcloud map. So it does not perform matching properly.

I had checked the ‘frame’ coordinates of moriyama quick start demo, and my custom environment.  Every coordinates are same. The only difference is, the pointcloud map is just beyond the ‘map’ frame. Moriyama demo’s pointcloud map is displayed far from ‘map’ frame, actually on the GPS coordinates.

So I had tried to shift the pointcloud map to the GPS coordinates, just as moriyama demo does. Firstly, I had tried using ‘TF’ to shift it, but pointcloud map in pcd file seems to be registered on ‘map’ frame directly. So I couldn’t modify its position using ‘TF’. Second, I had checked source code and launch file of ‘points_map_loader’ and ‘ndt_mapping’. But I failed to find out how to do.

Is there any way to solve this problem??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328511/have-trouble-in-%E2%80%98ndt-matching%E2%80%99-with-my-custom-pcd-file/) by [ktk1501](https://answers.ros.org/users/44057/ktk1501/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-07-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [miku54](https://answers.ros.org/users/73291/miku54/) on 2022-12-13**:
@gvdhoorn Hi, I have the same problem as you, can you please share the solution?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-12-13**:
I only edited the question, I did not post it.

**Comment by [miku54](https://answers.ros.org/users/73291/miku54/) on 2022-12-13**:
Oh my God! Do you know the reason for this problem?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-12-14**:
No, I don't.

I'd recommend checking the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two things I recommend:

1. Use `vel_pose_connect` to relay the topic `/ndt_pose` as `/current_pose` and your vehicle's current velocity from `/vehicle/twist` to `/current_velocity`. See the launch file below for this.
2. Provide an initial pose using RViz. To do this, open RViz and center on the `map` frame. Find your approximate location in the PCD map and click the "2D Pose Estimate" button at the top, and then click and drag from your current location on the map in the direction that the vehicle is facing.

Example `vel_pose_connect` launch:

```
<include file="$(find autoware_connector)/launch/vel_pose_connect.launch">
  <arg name="topic_pose_stamped" value="/ndt_pose" />
  <arg name="topic_twist_stamped" value="/vehicle/twist" />
</include>
```

The `/current_pose` is used in several nodes and Autoware doesn't make an assumption about which localizer you're using to output the current pose so it requires you to either remap or republish the `/ndt_pose` output from the NDT matching to the `/current_pose` topic. The `vel_pose_connect` launch script does this.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2019-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0